# User control property in windowsphone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I am planning on making a custom user control for Windows Phone 8. But what I want to make is a connection to a PLC and i don't want the user control to be visible on any page. I want the control to act like for example a timer in Windows Forms (so it is there, but not visible).

Also, i would like to add custom properties to my control that you can edit using the properties window in vs. How do i accomplish such thing?

I have read much information on the subject, but everything seems to create a visible control. And create properties that are set in xaml. Those are both things i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Then why do you want to create a custom control if it is not going to have a visual representation? Why can't you simply create a ordinary class with normal properties and events and use it instead?

That is what classes are for - encapsulating the logic in a structured way.

If you want a *visual* control, you create user controls. Otherwise, a class will suffice.

Comment: I want a user control, so i can set properties (that are now set in code behind, by hand). in the properties window of the control. This so my collegues who dont have any or not much c#/xaml knowledge can use this control to setup the connection with the plc relativly easy. This is why the usercontrol is a more convient way for them. (also, the connection to the plc i've allready made into a class).

Comment: If your control doesn't contain anything but the basic `Grid` control, it will be invisible.

Comment: Yeah, i kinda thought of that myself, but how can I set the properties in the VS properties windows for example if i want to set een endpoint IP adress. I want the user to input this in the properties window. And then use this in runtime (probably in the constructor of the usercontrol class).

Comment: Well, you are now in a lot of trouble I would say :) Properties that are visible in the XAML editor are called *dependency properties* and they are not your regular properties. How you will bind those properties to some code behind is a matter of choice.

Comment: So, as a summary What i want, is not possible for wp8?

Comment: No, it is possible and really easy to do. It just depends on your knowledge of XAML and you have to choose how exactly you want to do it.

Comment: Oké but making the properties appear in the VS properties window is also posible (even if done in the control's xaml)?

Comment: Yeah, dependency properties appear in XAML properties window.